# Is there a method in SAS Studio to separate a variable with a bimodal distribution?

Tags: sas, distribution, sas-studio

The variable that I am working with has a bimodal distribution. I need to figure out how to split the variable based on it's distribution. I want to do this programmatically in SAS studio instead of eyeballing it through a histogram.

Comment: Why would this be different in SAS Studio than in, for instance, SAS Enterprise Guide

Comment: Do you have any indication of de distribution of each modal?

Comment: One way is to create two clusters from your observations, another is to estimate the distribution from the observations. Both are discussed in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26876/separating-the-populations-in-a-bimodal-distribution, but not in a SAS context.